# can I have two react app in the same folder with the same package.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I want to run two apps using same package and node_modules, is this possible ?
I've a project with is already build with serverless framework but I want to put a single page along side it which will be created using react or next, so is it possible to do so.
and why I want to do so is that I want to consume some logic from the serverless inside the new react app

Comment: consider using a [monorepo](https://monorepo.tools/). Nx is a great solution.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to setup two different ports for the app and have npm scripts to start the server and then the client but it might complicate things as your application scale. So better to have two distinct projects instead.